# Workflow Send Email If All Subquestions in Survey are Answered

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a form that has rating questions and I want to send an email if all rating subquestions are answered, meaning every listed subquestion under the main question has one radio button selected. How can I achieve this in Designer? Kindly refer to the image below for reference. Thank you!

[image: Survey]

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. If you're building the form in InfoPath, you can check if all the questions are answered and set a column equal to a specific value that a workflow would either check and end the workflow or check and continue into the meat of the workflow. (Status: Begin Process vs Status: Form Closed)

Option 2. In the workflow, check that all columns have values and if they don't, skip into the end of the workflow.

Option 1 is better as you should be checking values at the form level. It's easier to change that than it is the workflow. If the fields are required, throw an error to the user that requires they fill out the form in order for the values to submit.

Comment: I'm not building it using InfoPath, so I'll be going with your 2nd option. Do you mean in the conditions of the workflow I should check all main questions if it is not empty?"Build Relationships: is not empty AND Learn Your Job: is not empty ...."

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Since your form is apparently letting through partial results, you'll have to check that 'Build Relationships 1', 'Build Relationships 2', 'Build Relationships 3', 'Build Relationships 4', 'Learn Your Job 1', etc all contain values. It's not going to be pretty, but you have a workflow doing what a form should be doing (checking that you have values). IMO: You may want to look up adding validation to your SP Designer form.

Comment: Yes the form should allow partial results. You suggested to add validations in the form level, are you suggesting me to make the main question required?

Comment: Whatever value you want to be the determining factor for whether or not a workflow begins. If that question has to be in there, why not validate around it. Alternatively, just take anything that doesn't have all the questions you want answered and status (via a custom column) the item as x instead of y and base the workflow behavior off of that.

Comment: The workflow begins when all subquestions has answers. So are you suggesting to put in a hidden checkbox that will check true if all subquestions are answered, then I put that checkbox in my worklow?

Comment: Correct. If that checkbox is not checked behind the scenes, the workflow looks at it and then ends it.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I will try your suggestion. Thank you! Hope it works. I'll get back to you when I'm done.